# How to get distinct value from table using ORM methods in odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

In Odoo, I have a model **"Email Rules"**, there is one column **number_of_days**.

Now what I need to do is to find **distinct number_of_days** from that model without fire query, I mean I want to use ORM methods not query.

How can I do this ?  I don't have much idea about this.

Odoo search_read and search methods to get data from table.

```
def search_read(self, cr, uid, domain=None, fields=None, offset=0, limit=None, order=None, context=None):
        """
        Performs a ``search()`` followed by a ``read()``.

        :param cr: database cursor
        :param user: current user id
        :param domain: Search domain, see ``args`` parameter in ``search()``. Defaults to an empty domain that will match all records.
        :param fields: List of fields to read, see ``fields`` parameter in ``read()``. Defaults to all fields.
        :param offset: Number of records to skip, see ``offset`` parameter in ``search()``. Defaults to 0.
        :param limit: Maximum number of records to return, see ``limit`` parameter in ``search()``. Defaults to no limit.
        :param order: Columns to sort result, see ``order`` parameter in ``search()``. Defaults to no sort.
        :param context: context arguments.
        :return: List of dictionaries containing the asked fields.
        :rtype: List of dictionaries.

        """


@api.returns('self')
    def search(self, cr, user, args, offset=0, limit=None, order=None, context=None, count=False):
        """ search(args[, offset=0][, limit=None][, order=None][, count=False])

        Searches for records based on the ``args``
        :ref:`search domain <reference/orm/domains>`.

        :param args: :ref:`A search domain <reference/orm/domains>`. Use an empty
                     list to match all records.
        :param int offset: number of results to ignore (default: none)
        :param int limit: maximum number of records to return (default: all)
        :param str order: sort string
        :param bool count: if True, only counts and returns the number of matching records (default: False)
        :returns: at most ``limit`` records matching the search criteria

        :raise AccessError: * if user tries to bypass access rules for read on the requested object.
        """
```

Now what do I need to do is to find out all the data first then make it unique by pythonic way which is quite repulsive.

So it would be great if anyone knows the smart solution for this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `distinct_field_get()`.
For example if you want to get distinct partners names, you can do it like this:

```
partners = self.env['res.partner']
values = partners.distinct_field_get(field='name', value='')
return set(values)
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt response!. but it doesn't response with unique data, I just have verified it.

Comment: @Emipro Technologies Pvt. Ltd. i missed `set`, sorry.

Comment: Thanks!. What to do if distinct value based on two or more fields ?

Comment: it's pythonic way, is there any pure ORM function that will return distinct data ?